# Background image does not show

Tags: asp.net, css

I am using ASP.NET Express to work on a site at cardinal14all.org.

When viewing the site in Design Mode, the background image shows fine, but not in the browser.

HTML:

```
<div id="content-wrap" >
```

CSS:

```
#content-wrap {
width: 1040px;
margin: 0 auto;
background: url('../Images/backingImage.png') repeat-y left top;
}
```

I've checked some other answers that relate to Forms Authentication and I'm not using that here so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background image shows up just fine, the problem is that the height of the element is zero, so you can't see it.

The `#content-wrap` element only contains floating elements, so they don't affect the height of the element.

Add `overflow: hidden;` to the style for the element, and it will contain its children.